# Fastest way to convert string array into object

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I have a `List<string[]> stringStudentList` where for each student array contains strings of all the properties. I need to convert this into the object Student in the fastest way possible.

For example `string[] student1 = {"Billy", "16", "3.32", "TRUE");` needs to be converted to the class:

```
class Student
{
    string name { get; set; }
    int age { get; set; }
    double gpa { get; set; }
    bool inHonors { get; set; }
}
```

Then inserted into a `List<Student>`. There are millions of students in `stringStudentList` so this has to be as fast as possible. I am currently following [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14254/Converting-CSV-Data-to-Objects) which grabs data from a CSV file but it is much too slow - takes several minutes to convert & parse the strings. How do I convert my list in the fastest way possible?

Comment: then make the List<string[]> change it to be `var lstObject = new List<Student>()` then the list can hold different datatypes..

Comment: There are many deserialization mechanisms for .NET, try out a few and see which one's the fastest for *your* use case(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular loop adding `new Student` into [pre-allocated list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx) would be quite fast:

```
//List<string[]> stringStudentList
var destination = new List<Student>(stringStudentList.Length);
foreach(var r in stringStudentList)
{
   destination.Add(new Student 
    {
      name =r[0],
      age = int.Parse(r[1]),
      gpa = double.Parse(r[2]),
      inHonors = r[3] == "TRUE"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a constructor for `Student` that takes a `string[]` as an argument:

```
Student(string[] profile)
{
    this.name = profile[0];
    this.age = int.Parse(profile[1]);
    this.gpa = double.Parse(profile[2]);
    this.inHonor = bool.Parse(profile[3]);
}
```

However, I think you should really look into Serialization in a situation like this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
var list students = new List<Student>();

foreach(var student in stringStudentList)
{
   students.Add(new Student
   {
       name = student[0]
       age = int.Parse(student[1]),
       gpa = double.Parse(student[2]),
       inHonors = bool.Parse(student[3])
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution..I can't believe I overlooked something so simple.